# how to render a object in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My Object is:

[image]

I want to get data from recette-... such as base64

```
    const articleList = Object.keys(this.state.users).map(key => {
    Object( this.state.users[key].recettes).map(data => {
      // Object.entries( data ).map(infos => {
      //   console.log(infos + data)
      // })  
      console.log(data)
      })
})
```

Comment: Is your question about how to render base64 images in React or how to iterate over a JS object?

Comment: what do you mean render an object ?

Comment: you want to render the object as string? if yes, you can use JSON.stringify(object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing your base64 encoded image as a direct source of an Image object.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class Example extends Component {
   state = {
      images: []
   };


   componentDidMount(){
     let images = [];
     let keys = [];
     Object.keys(this.state.users).map(key => {
        keys.push(key);
     });
     keys.map(_key => {
        Object.keys(this.state.users[`${_key}`].recettes).map(key=> {
            let image = new Image();
            image.src = this.state.users[`${_key}`].recettes[`${key}`].base64;
            images.push(image);
        });
     }); 
     this.setState({images: images});
   }


   render(){
     return(
       <div>
         {this.state.images}
       </div>
     )
   }
}
```

Now I might have made a mistake in parsing your data because I only have them in an image and cannot see the output of what I wrote to verify and debug but you get the idea. Also, I broke down a bit the process of collecting the object keys to make it a bit more readable and reduce the number of the nested loops. The point is that you should parse your data as you were going to, and once you reach the point where you have access to the base64 image, you pass it as a source to a new image and let the state handle the rest. Hope this works and helps.

Comment: Hi, thnaks for your response, nevertheless, I have this error:
×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'kevin' of undefined
  `let keys = []; Object.key(this.state.users).map(key => { keys.push(key); }); keys.map(_key => {`

Comment: Yes thats cause I missed the s from keys, I edited the snippet. But don't rely on it, just parse your data as you would do it normally and when you reach the point where you have access to the base64 image, use it as source and let the state handle the rest.

Comment: I editted again the code snippet and replaced Object.values with Object.keys. Also I missed an s from this.state.users, I typed this.state.user